# Move folders to another folder according to CSV data

Tags: csv, batch-file, directory, move

I hope you could help me, I have a folder with hundreds of folders named from.reports files ( ex. 123456, 098765, etc) then I have a CSV file with data to assign each report to a person

Example:

> 123456.   Name1
>   345678.   Name2
>   654387.   Name3
>   873490.   Name1

Is there a way to.make batch file to read the CSV and move the folders to their respective person?

Example:
C:\folder\123456 move to C:\folder\Name1\123456
C:\folder\345687 move to C:\folder\Name2\345587
...
Etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "data.csv" is located in the working directory of the script:

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=. " %%# in (data.csv) do (
    md C:\folder\%%$
    move "C:\folder\%%#" "C:\folder\%%$"
)
```

This first creates the C:\folder\NameN directories, then moves C:\folder\NUMBER into the according directories.

Comment: It doesn't work I get a message saying: sysem can't find the file data.csv and its there

Comment: @basichmx Does your csv contain spaces in the filename or is it actually data.csv?